# Apache load php pages as text

Tags: php, apache, debian

I got a problem with Apache2 server. 
Im using VDS with Debian OS.
Server dysplay all files as plain text.

Here example: [click](http://213.159.209.165/)

Apache configuration:

```
<VirtualHost 213.159.209.165:80>
    ServerName pixellot.ru
    AddDefaultCharset off
    AssignUserID romancasper romancasper
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    DocumentRoot /var/www/romancasper/data/www/pixellot.ru
    ServerAdmin webmaster@pixellot.ru
    ServerAlias www.pixellot.ru
    CustomLog /var/www/httpd-logs/pixellot.ru.access.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/www/httpd-logs/pixellot.ru.error.log
    <FilesMatch "\.ph(p[3-5]?|tml)$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.phps$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
    </FilesMatch>
    php_admin_value sendmail_path "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f webmaster@pixellot.ru"
    php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir "/var/www/romancasper/data/mod-tmp"
    php_admin_value session.save_path "/var/www/romancasper/data/mod-tmp"
    php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/romancasper/data:."
</VirtualHost>
<Directory />
    #Options FollowSymLinks
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/romancasper/data/www/pixellot.ru>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

What i need to do?

Comment: make sure php is installed.

Comment: @Criesto apt-get install php5 php-pear php5-mysql. Result > php5 is already the newest version.

Comment: did you restart apache ? `service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 0):

```
<FilesMatch "\.phps$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
</FilesMatch>
```

replace with:

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
</FilesMatch>
```

or change app type to: application/octet-stream or text/html

Comment: Nothing after replace.
Where should i change AppType?

Comment: inside FilesMatch tags: SetHandler application/octet-stream